# not getting output for euler challenge 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, primes

I am attempting to solve [Project Euler: Problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3), and I am using the following function to test for primality,

```
def check_prime(x):
    i = 1
    b = 0
    while b == 0 :
        i += 1
        if i >= x :
            return True 
            b += 1
        elif  x%i  == 0 :
            return False
            b += 1
```

Which I call from the rest of my program

```
a = 3
z = []
number_used = 600851475143
while a < number_used/2 :
    if check_prime(a) and number_used%a == 0 :
        z.append(a);
        a += 2
    else :
        a += 2  
        print z
```

But, the code is not printing the  prime factors needed for the third Euler problem. Is my code too inefficient to manage it?

Comment: Are you aware of [Therac-25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25). They also used `b+=1` for controlling flags

Comment: to increase your chances of getting help consider fixing your indentation of the code you post.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure you format your code properly when pasting into a post. In it's current form that code doesn't compile. Lol4t0-s answer is a nice reference to a historical programming flaw, however it is totally unrelated. In fact `b+=1` will never run in your code.

Comment: if you have the same statement in the `if`and `else` clause, you can just pull it out of the if/else (e.g., `a += 2`)

Comment: Your code is inefficient yes, as it does redoes a lot of calculations when checking primality. However, the inefficiency is not the reason that you are not computing the correct answer. You might want to familiarize yourself with the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) and the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) as algorithms for determining if a number is prime and finding all primes up to the square root of 600851475143.

Comment: It's doubtful that you want to print `z` that frequently and the body of your function needs to be indented. And as already mentioned, the `b += 1` statements will never be executed since they occur after `return` statements.

Comment: thank you all for the help. I managed to figure out the problem.

Comment: also hoping your variables are capable of storing the values ... `600851475143` is not exactly small number ...